# Google API for search data

Tags: search, google-api

Is there a Google API to get the following:

1. How often a search query is entered (Per month) into Google?
2. Where a site ranks for a particular search term?

Answer (score 1):

1. There is some data on search volumes available via the AdWords API Keyword tool at http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/TrafficEstimatorService.html
2. Not really. There is some limited data available via Google Webmaster tools for domains that you own but it doesn't report on all keywords and it can't be pulled via the API yet.

Comment: For part 2 I found I could pull data from Google Custom Search API, although I still have some issues with results differing from the main Google search. Not sure if this is cache, a different algorithm or that my general search uses google.co.uk, not sure what is used by the custom search api?